# Android - custom licensing server - does this go against the Market Agreement?

Tags: android, licensing

I've searched around for information on this, but I am not sure what exactly is deemed "right".

I have an app I am about to publish (hopefully to Market). Its a very specialized app, and needs no marketing really. We were just going to publish on our own webserver, but many users have issues installing non-market apks (its going around by email right now to test). So we decided to publish to market.

We have a custom licensing server in place that links any X phones to a users account on our webserver. The user can login (desktop or mobile) and purchase licenses through paypal. This allows the user to use however many phones they need to, all being linked to their account on our website.

Is this violating the terms of use for Google Market? I remember reading somewhere that if you have a license purchasing procedure in place, that it is not against their TOS. Am I at risk of having my app removed by doing this (allowing users to purchase licenses through MY site, after the trial ends, instead of google market)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: Go ahead, I've been done with this for years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The android market agreement says

3.3 You may also choose to distribute Products for free. If the Product is free, you will not be charged a Transaction Fee. You may not collect future charges from users for copies of the Products that those users were initially allowed to download for free. This is not intended to prevent distribution of free trial versions of the Product with an "upsell" option to obtain the full version of the Product: Such free trials for Products are encouraged. However, if you want to collect fees after the free trial expires, you must collect all fees for the full version of the Product through the Payment Processor on the Market. In this Agreement, "free" means there are no charges or fees of any kind for use of the Product. All fees received by Developers for Products distributed via the Market must be processed by the Market's Payment Processor.

So unless providing the app through your own website, I guess your system would violate the agreement

Comment: Well I guess my next question is, do most phones allow or disallow apk installations from websites?

Comment: All phones support installation of apk's that are not downloaded from Android Market, though it requires 'applications -> unknown sources' to be enabled. Refer to http://m.androidcentral.com/allow-app-installs-unknown-sources